# Array of a floating point numbers that sum to value b. given an integer number c, how do i make sure that sum(each array element / c) == b / c

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have an array `a` of floating point numbers (2 decimal precision) that sum to value `b`.

Let's say I have an integer number *c*.

I need to figure out an algorithm where `sum(roundedToNearestPenny(each array element / c)) == roundUpToNearestPenny(b / c)`.

For example:

Array `a`: [25.33, 25.28, 19.38]
Sum of array elements `b`: 69.99

Integer Number `c`: 5

`roundedUpToNearestPenny(b / c)` = 14.00

I need to come up with an algorithm where dividing each number in the array by `c` and rounding them to pennies results in the same number as rounding b / c up to the nearest penny.

Always rounding each division on the elements in the array in the same direction does not always produce the same results.

Comment: You do not want to do any rounding until the very end.

Comment: What are the exact specifications of `roundedToNearestPenny` and `roundedUpToNearestPenny`? Assuming they are supposed to be the same rounding mode, and that this rounding mode is one of the standard IEEE-754 rounding modes, I am reasonably sure that the answer is "you can't".